Typescript problem with Window object property
Minor but annoying problem, I'm implementing Scalderone in my chat app and Typescript always gives me this error:
"Property 'Scaledrone' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)"
 drone = new window.Scaledrone('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
        data: meRef.current,
    });

"Scalderone" part is underlined in red

You can declare Scaledrone as property of window
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Scaledrone:(key:string,props:unkown)=>void;
  }
}
let Scaledrone = window.Scaledrone;

Also remember you need to create a index.d.ts and add the above code there, if it is not there

i found index.d.ts in typescript-eslint/dist folder, hope thats the right one. I also declared it at beginning of my app.tsx. That ts error thing dissapeared but now i cannot connect to Scalderone. I get this in console: "scaledrone.min.js:283 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'args')"

aha, it's bc your code doesn't have "new" before Scalderone.

Make sure oo include the Scaledrone library in the head section of your HTML file.
<script src='https://cdn.scaledrone.com/scaledrone.min.js'></script>

You can read more about it from Scaledrone's documentation.

OK, i found the solution that works best for me. feel free to correct me if it's insufficient:
 let drone: any = null;
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Scaledrone: (a: any) => void;
    }
}
let Scaledrone = window.Scaledrone as any;

drone = new Scaledrone('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
            data: meRef.current,
        });

